# Owin Katana with MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, owin, katana

As mention below statement from Article link how we can implement in MVC?

Katana allows you to build web based applications, such as MVC or Web API (2) where you can decide which web features to include in the project.

[Article link](https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/04/14/owin-and-katana-part-1-the-basics/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Katana is no longer being developed. According to their [roadmap](https://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=roadmap&referringTitle=Home),

> The next major version of Katana is part of the ASP.NET vNext project on GitHub

"ASP.NET vNext" is the early name for what is now [ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/). The architecture of ASP.NET Core continues (and improves on) the modular architecture that Katana used. You can build an ASP.NET Core MVC project using only the packages you need.

For further reading, check out my answers to [Is Owin/Katana supposed to replace Web API?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800694/3191599) and [Does ASP.NET Core still use OWIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38726780/3191599)

Comment: Can we use .cshtml extension or razor pages(.aspx extension) without system.web dll through Owin/Katana application in mvc core.

Comment: Thanks Nate,  i have installed vs 2015 web express is it enough to implement this type application on window 7, or need something more.